# how can upload file to server in Vue file manager?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

how can upload file to server in Vue file manager?

if the user created the new directory or upload files, and how can I know the user create folder or upload file path?

this is my template

```
<template>
  <div class="FileManagement">
    <va-inner-loading :loading="isLoading">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="flex xs12 md12">
          <DxFileManager
            :file-system-provider="dataSource"
            current-path="Widescreen"
            
          >
            <DxPermissions
              :create="true"
              :copy="true"
              :move="true"
              :delete="true"
              :rename="true"
              :upload="true"
              :download="true"
            />
          </DxFileManager>
        </div>
      </div>
    </va-inner-loading>
  </div>
</template>
```

I found this methods

```
$(function() {
    $("#fileManagerContainer").dxFileManager({
        // ...
        onCurrentDirectoryChanged: function(e) {
            // Your code goes here
        }
    });
});
```

but it was not working.

btw, I used this plugin.

https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxFileManager/

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever used the HTML input tag? The file path can be obtained by V-model and watch.

```
    <input type="file" v-model="input"></input>    
      data() {
        return {
         input:''
        };
      },
      watch:{
        input(nval,oval){
          console.log(nval)
        }
      },
```

Comment: No, I don't use html input tag. I just use template element

Comment: <el-input type="file" v-model="input" ></el-input>